# Cake Auth component only works in one browser

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I developed an app locally with Cakephp 2.8 over MAMP and testing with Chrome. I implemented users login with Auth component following the manual and a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvwQGZ1BxdM).
Everything worked well, but when I finished the app I tried to login in Safari and Firefox, and it didn't work. I get the authentication error with a wrong password but with the right one, login redirects me to the home page (the index of my Jugadores controller) and the actions protected by Auth can never be accessed, I'm asked to login over and over like the if session is never created.
When I deployed my app in a live server, it worked in no browser, this makes me think I'm doing something wrong but I'm can't find what.

Here is the code in my AppController:

```
<?php

App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'jugadores', 'action' => 'index'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'jugadores', 'action' => 'index'),
        'authError' => 'You can not access that page.',
        'authorize' => array('Controller')
        )
    );

    public function isAuthorized($user) {
        return true; //for simplicity. Is it wrong?
    }

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->allow('view','index');
    }

}
?>
```

And my Users controller is:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class UsersController extends AppController {

    public $components = array('Paginator', 'Flash', 'Session');

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
    }


    public function login() {
        if($this->request->is('post')){
            if($this->Auth->login()){
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            } else {
                $this->Flash->set('Wrong user/password.');
            }
        }
    }

    public function logout(){
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }

}
?>
```

The login view looks like this:

```
<div class="users view">
<h2>Login</h2>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('User');
    echo $this->Form->input('username');
    echo $this->Form->input('password');
    echo $this->Form->end('Enter');

?>
</div>
```

For the users database I followed the Cakephp conventions. Fields: id, username, password, role, created, modified

**EDIT:** I placed this in the beforeRender function of the AppController:

```
$this->set('current_user', $this->Auth->user());
```

And printed it in the layout default.ctp with:

```
print_r($current_user);
```

Chrome always prints the logged in user data when testing in local server, but Firefox and Safari only print when requesting an Auth protected action (and takes me to login page).
In live server all browsers act the same (logged user data not always appears).
So I think in some way Auth is working and creating a session, but not behaving as it should.

Comment: What's your form method?

Comment: The method is post.
I discovered something else. Editing the question

Comment: Forget about this. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

I tried implementing Auth in a fresh copy of CakePHP 2.8.0-RC1 and got the same result.
Then I tried in a fresh copy of CakePHP 2.7.9 and everything worked as expected in all browsers and servers, even after copying my controllers, views, and the rest of my app to this installation :D

So... this looks like a bug of the 2.8.0-RC1 version.